# Html collection has a .length but undefined .item(*)

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calls to an xml page, picks out elements by the tag names, and I'm trying to call back a specific one.  code so far is:

```
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("test.xml");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
var PittWins = x.item(2);
```

This will come back [object element]

```
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("test.xml");
 var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
var PittWins = x[2].data;
```

The above code gives me undefined.

```
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("nhl.xml");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
var PittWins = x.length;
```

when entered above, i get a result which is correct.

I am trying to understand why it's giving me a length and not a specific node..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `var PittWins = x[2];`?

---

#### Re: OP edit

You're saying that `x.item(2)` and `x.length` return what you expect, but `x[2].data` does not? Why do you expect the element to have a `data` property? Are you trying to write the bracketed version of `x.item(2)`?

`x.item(2)` is equivalent to `x[2]`.
`x.item(2).data` is equivalent to `x[2].data`.

What are you trying to do? Also, you've used different XML file names and tag names across your different examples. Is this intentional?

---

#### Edit #2

To retrieve the text content of an element, use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) or [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue). Your code might look like this, then:

```
var PittWins = x[2].textContent;
```

Comment: it's essentially the same  the brackets and .item.   however, i forgot to add a bit of information that i just edited in

Comment: Matt, sorry for the confusion.  I am new to coding.  I realize the equivalencies you have mentioned.  I am trying to get a text value for a node, and assumed that's what the '.data' did.  anyway you know of to get a text value?  'x.item(2)' returns [Element Object] -which is right-, i am wanting the text value, though.

Comment: @Shawn: aha! As you have found, `.data` does not get you the text value. I assume you want the text within the element (and not, say, an attribute)? See my edit.

Comment: @Shawn: try using a debugger, like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox, or the Developer Tools which are built-in to Chrome and Safari. It will make your life **so much** easier.